Android Room question. Why there is a difference between the presence and absence of the init block
I observe an issue when Room.databaseBuilder.build() is executed as part of a property initialization. It works though when called from an init block:
class GalleryRepository private constructor(context: Context) {
    private val callback = object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
        override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            val now = System.currentTimeMillis()
            db.execSQL("insert into photo ( location, date, src) values ('test', ${now}, '@drawable/apple');")
        }
    }

    private val database: GalleryDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(
        context.applicationContext,
        GalleryDatabase::class.java,
        DATABASE_NAME,
    ).addCallback(callback).build()

    private val galleryDao = database.galleryDao()

    fun getPhotosFlow(): Flow<List<PhotoEntity>> = galleryDao.getPhotosFlow()

    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE: GalleryRepository? = null

        fun initialize(context: Context) {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = GalleryRepository(context)
            }
        }

        fun getInstance(): GalleryRepository {
            return INSTANCE ?: throw IllegalStateException("GalleryRepository must be initialized")
        }
    }
}

I was wondering if it was because of the kapt I put in while using Binding Adapter, so it works well outside the init block after I removed all kapt code, and I'm wondering why there is a difference between the presence and absence of the init block.
The following code works. Why is that? What's the difference?
private lateinit var database: GalleryDatabase

private val callBack = object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
// ... insert queries

    init {
        Log.d(TAG, "init...........: ")
        try {
            database = Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                GalleryDatabase::class.java,
                DATABASE_NAME,
            ).addCallback(callBack).build()

            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                Log.d(TAG, "success!!: ${
                    database.galleryDao().getAllPhotos()
                }")
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d(TAG, "exception!!: ")
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}


I suggest proofreading your question and updating for clarity. I, personally, have no idea what you're asking. For example, "line 12 builds are executed"? What? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Since it was still hard to understand after your edit I've rewritten it as I understood. Please verify this is what you intended to ask.

@Leviathan Thanks to you, I'll be able to ask questions well

You still need to explain what you mean by “works” and “doesn’t work” for us to be able to understand what you’re asking. Doesn’t work could mean a million different things because we don’t know exactly what you were expecting, or, if it’s a runtime or compile error we don’t want to have to recreate your whole project to find out what it is.
